# numpy cumulative sum ordered on argsort indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**Background**

I am trying to calculate the "social traveler" distance between a set of points. For two points *a* and *b*, we define *ST(a,b)* as the cumulative sum of euclidean distances between *a* and all points *closer* to *a* than *b*, up to and including *b*.

(Imagine *a* is making various trips to see people. They first see the nearest person, then the next nearest, and so on. The social-traveler distance is how much they will have traveled (counting only the outgoing distance) by the time they reach *b*.)

Social traveler distance is defined up to some arbitrary radius; beyond that the "visited" point is defined as unreachable. This is because reasons. ;)

**What I have done so far**

I have a numpy array with points. A toy example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([(0,0), (-1,2), (-2,-2), (6,-2), (4,0)])
>>> x
array([[ 0,  0],
       [-1,  2],
       [-2, -2],
       [ 6, -2],
       [ 4,  0]])
```

I generate an array with the pairwise distances between each point. For this example, distance 4 is the upper limit I consider.

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
>>> y = pairwise_distances(x)
>>> y
array([[0.  , 2.24, 2.83, 6.32, 4.  ],
       [2.24, 0.  , 4.12, 8.06, 5.39],
       [2.83, 4.12, 0.  , 8.  , 6.32],
       [6.32, 8.06, 8.  , 0.  , 2.83],
       [4.  , 5.39, 6.32, 2.83, 0.  ]])
>>> import numpy.ma as ma
>>> ym = ma.masked_greater(y, 4)
>>> ym
masked_array(
  data=[[0.0 , 2.24, 2.83,   --, 4.0 ],
        [2.24, 0.0 ,   --,   --,   --],
        [2.83,   --, 0.0 ,   --,   --],
        [  --,   --,   --, 0.0 , 2.83],
        [4.0 ,   --,   --, 2.83, 0.0 ]],
  mask=[[False, False, False,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
        [False,  True, False,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True, False, False],
        [False,  True,  True, False, False]],
  fill_value=1e+20)
```

(I have truncated numbers for everyone's sanity.)

My goal here is to replace each row element with the cumulative sum of the row's non-missing values up to and including that element. (For simplicity, ignore the issue of ties.) That is, **I want to get this array**:

```
>>> hypothetical_new_y
array([[0.  , 2.24, 5.06,  nan, 9.06],
       [2.24, 0.  ,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [2.83,  nan, 0.  ,  nan,  nan],
       [nan ,  nan,  nan, 0.  , 2.83],
       [6.83,  nan,  nan, 2.83, 0.  ]])
```

I know how to get the cumulative sum along the rows:

```
>>> np.cumsum(ym, axis=1)
masked_array(
  data=[[0.0 , 2.24, 5.06,   --, 9.06],
        [2.24, 2.24,   --,   --,   --],
        [2.83,   --, 2.83,   --,   --],
        [  --,   --,   --, 0.0 , 2.83],
        [4.0 ,   --,   --, 6.83, 6.83]],
...
```

Because this is adding based on the row order rather than sorting, it gives incorrect values (except by coincidence on the first row here). I can do the same, first sorting the rows:

```
>>> np.cumsum(np.sort(ym, axis=1), axis=1)
masked_array(
  data=[[0.0 , 2.24, 5.06, 9.06,   --],
        [0.0 , 2.24,   --,   --,   --],
        [0.0 , 2.83,   --,   --,   --],
        [0.0 , 2.83,   --,   --,   --],
        [0.0 , 2.83, 6.83,   --,   --]],
  mask=[[False, False, False, False,  True],
        [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
        [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
        [False, False,  True,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False,  True,  True]],
  fill_value=1e+20)
```

This gives me the correct values, but they are sorted in ascending value rather than in the order I want. I want these cumulative sums positioned in accordance with the original array's *argsort* values:

```
>>> np.argsort(ym)
array([[0, 1, 2, 4, 3],
       [1, 0, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 0, 1, 3, 4],
       [3, 4, 0, 1, 2],
       [4, 3, 0, 1, 2]])
```

It seems I need a way to sort these rows, do the cumulative sums, and then return the cumulative sums sorted by those argsort vectors. Notice that if you present the results of `np.cumsum(np.sort(ym, axis=1), axis=1)` ordered by the vectors in `np.argsort(ym)`, you have my `hypothethical_new_y` array. But it's this last step where I'm falling on my face.

I feel like I have two-thirds of a Venn diagram here. Any thoughts on how I can take this last step? My hope is that this is a relatively simple gap in my numpy-syntax knowledge that I've uncovered.

EDIT: After posting this and continuing to dig, I thought I had found the "obvious" answer with `np.take_along_axis()`--but no. Consider this code:

```
>>> foo = np.argsort(ym)
>>> bar = np.cumsum(np.sort(ym, axis=1), axis=1)
>>> np.take_along_axis(bar, foo, axis=1)
masked_array(
  data=[[0.0 , 2.24, 5.06,   --, 9.06],
        [2.24, 0.0 ,   --,   --,   --],
        [  --, 0.0 , 2.83,   --,   --],
        [  --,   --, 0.0 , 2.83,   --],
        [  --,   --, 0.0 , 2.83, 6.83]],
...
```

If you look at the last row, for example, it is clear that the command is taking the 4th element of the last row of `bar` and putting it in the first spot, the 3rd element of the last row of `bar` and putting it in the second spot, etc. (Recall that the last row of foo is `[4, 3, 0, 1, 2]`.) What I want instead is to take the **1st** element of the last row of `bar` and put it in the **fourth** spot, the **2nd** element of  `bar` and put it in the **third** spot, etc. And `np.put_along_axis` isn't my jam, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for not understanding the requirements. I gave it another shot and came up with this. I couldn’t figure out how to do this with a for loop, but the output appears to match your hypothetical_new_y, with the exception of a rounding issues in line one. But I think the logic should hold.

```
>>> x
array([[ 0.  ,  2.24,  2.83,  6.32,  4.  ],
       [ 2.24,  0.  ,  4.12,  8.06,  5.39],
       [ 2.83,  4.12,  0.  ,  8.  ,  6.32],
       [ 6.32,  8.06,  8.  ,  0.  ,  2.83],
       [ 4.  ,  5.39,  6.32,  2.83,  0.  ]])
>>> ym
masked_array(data =
 [[0.0 2.24 2.83 -- 4.0]
 [2.24 0.0 -- -- --]
 [2.83 -- 0.0 -- --]
 [-- -- -- 0.0 2.83]
 [4.0 -- -- 2.83 0.0]],
             mask =
 [[False False False  True False]
 [False False  True  True  True]
 [False  True False  True  True]
 [ True  True  True False False]
 [False  True  True False False]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)

>>> g=np.cumsum(np.sort(ym, axis=1), axis=1)
>>> g
masked_array(data =
 [[0.0 2.24 5.07 9.07 --]
 [0.0 2.24 -- -- --]
 [0.0 2.83 -- -- --]
 [0.0 2.83 -- -- --]
 [0.0 2.83 6.83 -- --]],
             mask =
 [[False False False False  True]
 [False False  True  True  True]
 [False False  True  True  True]
 [False False  True  True  True]
 [False False False  True  True]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
>>> n = np.zeros_like(x, dtype=float).view(np.ma.masked_array)
>>> for i in range(n.shape[0]):
...         n[i][x[i].argsort(axis=0)] = g.data[i]
...         
>>> 
>>> n.mask = ym.mask
>>> n
masked_array(data =
 [[0.0 2.24 5.07 -- 9.07]
 [2.24 0.0 -- -- --]
 [2.83 -- 0.0 -- --]
 [-- -- -- 0.0 2.83]
 [6.83 -- -- 2.83 0.0]],
             mask =
 [[False False False  True False]
 [False False  True  True  True]
 [False  True False  True  True]
 [ True  True  True False False]
 [False  True  True False False]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

A bit clunky, and if I’m wrong again I’ll run up the white flag

Comment: Apologies for not responding sooner--if I just say "global pandemic," hopefully that explains?

Comment: This does indeed produce the desired array! The question now is whether there is a way to remove the for-loop in there, just for efficiency's sake. But this takes the problem to a new stage, for which I am very grateful.

Comment: @JPFerguson, yeah the whole world is moving at a different speed these days . Maybe your code will help us return to normal that much quicker! I worked on getting rid of the for-loop to no avail. Glad to help.